# Performance decrease due to shift work

Tags: research

I was wondering if there are any studies that show that inconsistent shift work has a negative impact on worker performance.
In addition, I was wondering if there is any evidence on how performance develops then? Does it decrease linearly, exponentially or otherwise?
I would be really grateful for any help.

Comment: There is an enormous body of research on the deleterious effects of shift work, especially rotating shift work. What were your search terms?

Comment: Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to ask how "performance" would decrease in terms of linear, exponential, etc, as the functional form will necessarily depend on how performance is measured including any relevant floor or ceiling effects.